# webclient.DownloadFile not working in a for loop

Tags: for-loop, webclient

I faced a problem. I had called the webclient.DownloadFile in a for loop.
When ran, it either downloaded just first file, or never downloaded anything. And always gave file not found 404 error. But if I run it in debug mode with breakpoint before the call, and then step over, it downloaded the file every time.

Finally I was able to solve the problem with adding sleep just before the call.
If I add the sleep couple of statements earlier, it did not work. It has to be just before the call.

```
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            client.DownloadFile(srcUrl, destFilePath);
```

Now it downloaded every file without breakpoint.

Hope this helps someone. Spent like 3 4 days on this.

Comment: What kind of programming language do you use?

Comment: HI Koen, I use C# for the coding.